# Не могу решить вопрос. TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str и работа с iapws.iapws97

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

Решаю задачу по машинному обучению, остановился на задаче предобработки данных. У меня есть датасет, который содержит в себе 300к строк. Нужно провести предобработку данных, связанную с суммированием, усреднением и тд. Эту часть решил быстро.
Столкнулся с проблемой связанную с библиотекой iapws.iapws97
Нужно найти энтальпию с помощью данной библиотеки. https://iapws.readthedocs.io/en/latest/iapws.iapws97.html#iapws.iapws97._Region2
Пример из документации дается такой:

```
>>> in: _Region2(700,30)["h"]
>>> Out: 2631.49474
```

Но при использовании такого примера у себя выдает ошибку, хотя я установил библиотеку:

```
NameError: name '_Region2' is not defined
```

Я же использую такой вариант:

```
df['IO'] = (df['T_PO'],df['D_PO'])['h']
```

И получаю такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Мои извилины уже отсыхают, не могу решить данную задачу

UPD:

```
pip install iapws
from iapws import IAPWS97
df['IO'] = 0 #Здесь не важно, создаю ли я отдельно столбец, здесь для 
             #понимания что он заполняется
df['IO'] = (df['T_PO'],df['D_PO'])['h']
```

Comment: (df['T_PO'],df['D_PO'])['h'] - Вы создаёте tuple (df['T_PO'],df['D_PO']) и хотите из него взять как из словаря?

Comment: Я пытался привести данную запись к виду как в примере, но не смог. То есть если в примере используются просто числа, то у меня это столбцы с числами.

Comment: Конечно установил, возможно где-то туплю с импортом модуля

Comment: Кусок кода в вопрос добавте, где там имполт и вызов с параментами _Region2

Comment: как вызываете _Region2 ?   iapws97._Region2(T, P) ?

Comment: На самом деле как я только не пытался вызывать _Region2. Он всегда пишет что не объявлен аргумент, любой, будь то _Region2,  iapws97 или  iapws

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал в `Google Colab`, всё прекрасно ставится и работает. Просто мало поставить библиотеку, нужно ещё импортировать:

```
# pip install iapws

from iapws.iapws97 import _Region2

print(_Region2(700,30)["h"])
```

Вывод:

```
2631.4947448448074
```

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно работает. Но теперь я вернулся к основной проблеме TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str

Comment: я же писал - так нельза делать - из tuple не всзять значение как из словаря